# Can caffeine act as viagra

Tags: molecular-biology, endocrinology, receptor

Recently I studied that cAMP which is a 2° messenger can cause various physiolocal changes under the action of proper hormones. Now cAMP is degraded by phosphodiesterase and this ceases the actions. Viagra drugs like sildenafil are phophodiesterase inhibitors and therefore prolong cAMP action. Also caffeine inhibits phosphodiesterase and therefore it should cause a similar phenomenon. But does it actually happen? Or some other mechanism stop it from happening. What are those mechanisms?

Comment: Is sildenafil a "phophodiesterase inhibitor"? Or is it a specific inhibitor of a particular phophodiesterase? If the latter, which one? How potent is it vs. caffeine?

Comment: To put it in everyday terms: caffeine raises blood pressure, and this is pretty much the same effect as that of viagra, just less specific and less long-lasting.

Comment: Didn't realize this Q only had DVs... given the amount of totally crap questions here that somehow get a lot of upvotes, this one was treated rather harshly... I mean we know the answer because it was actually investigated and published, so it wasn't a totally outlandish Q to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much luck there. Although caffeine, sildenafil and cGMP share a basic ring structure, the specificity and potency of caffeine for PDE5 is rather [underwhelming](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/j.1939-4640.2003.tb02744.x):

> On the basis of comparative IC50 values, the potency of sildenafil is about 1 million times higher than that of caffeine (Corbin and Francis, 1999).

Comment: This is a lot of coffee.